# How to remove extra array level with nil value from a returned array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this code which is *almost* giving me what I want.

```
def merge_data(keys, data)

merged_data = keys.map {|hash| data.first.map {|k,v| if hash.values.first == k then hash.merge(v) end}}

end
```

See below for the difference between the expected (first) and actual return value:

```
-[{:awesomeness=>10,
   -  :first_name=>"blake",
   -  :height=>"74",
   -  :last_name=>"johnson"},
   - {:awesomeness=>9, :first_name=>"ashley", :height=>60, :last_name=>"dubs"}]

   +[[{:awesomeness=>10,
   +   :first_name=>"blake",
   +   :height=>"74",
   +   :last_name=>"johnson"},
   +  nil],
   + [nil,
   +  {:awesomeness=>9, :first_name=>"ashley", :height=>60, :last_name=>"dubs"}]]
```

If anyone could explain why I'm getting an extra array level with an index of nil it would be much appreciated!

Based upon the below data:

```
let(:keys) {[
       {:first_name => "blake"},
       {:first_name => "ashley"}
]}

  let(:data) {[
       {"blake" => {
            :awesomeness => 10,
                 :height => "74",
              :last_name => "johnson"},
        "ashley" => {
            :awesomeness => 9,
                 :height => 60,
              :last_name => "dubs"}
    }
 ]}

  let(:merged_data) {[
       {:first_name => "blake",
        :awesomeness => 10,
             :height => "74",
          :last_name => "johnson"},

       {:first_name => "ashley",
        :awesomeness => 9,
             :height => 60,
          :last_name => "dubs"}
]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its because you are mapping keys and keys are two, if `data` does not contain the `hash.values.first` then it returns `nil`. But do you really need an hash with keys since keys are already keys in data?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just needed a fine-tuning:

```
def merge_data(keys, data)
  merged_data = keys.map {|hash| data.first.map {|k,v| if hash.values.first == k then hash.merge(v) end }.compact[0] }
end

keys = [{:first_name => "blake"}, {:first_name => "ashley"}]

data = [
  {"blake" => {
       :awesomeness => 10,
            :height => "74",
         :last_name => "johnson"},
   "ashley" => {
       :awesomeness => 9,
            :height => 60,
         :last_name => "dubs"}
  }]

puts  merge_data(keys, data).inspect

#=>
[ 
  {
    :first_name=>"blake",
    :awesomeness=>10,
    :height=>"74",
    :last_name=>"johnson"},
  {
    :first_name=>"ashley",
    :awesomeness=>9,
    :height=>60,
    :last_name=>"dubs"
  }
]
```

**What was changed??**

Added `.compact[0]` in the inner block.

Why? Because it is a `map` running on each key and each data values. Returning nil for one that does not match the other and returning an array each time instead of a `Hash` object.

However, we can create a custom class and reconstruct the data later:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :height, :awesomeness
  def initialize(first_name)
    @first_name = first_name
  end

  def update(info)
    info.each do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) if respond_to?(key)
    end
  end

  def to_h
    { first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, awesomeness: self.awesomeness, height: self.height }
  end
end

people = keys.each_with_object({}) do |k, person_map|
  person_map[k[:first_name]] = Person.new(k[:first_name])
end

data.each do |people_info|
  people_info.each do |first_name, info|
    if people[first_name]
      people[first_name].update(info)
    end
  end
end

p people.values.map{ |p| p.to_h }

#=> [{:first_name=>"blake", :last_name=>"johnson", :awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74"}, {:first_name=>"ashley", :last_name=>"dubs", :awesomeness=>9, :height=>60}]
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Given the data set:

```
data = {
        "blake" => {
            :awesomeness => 10,
                 :height => "74",
              :last_name => "johnson"},
        "ashley" => {
            :awesomeness => 9,
                 :height => 60,
              :last_name => "dubs"}
        }
```

Why not just like this?

```
data.map { |h| h.last.merge({first_name: h.first}) }

#=> [{:awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74", :last_name=>"johnson", :first_name=>"blake"}, {:awesomeness=>9, :height=>60, :last_name=>"dubs", :first_name=>"ashley"}]
```

---

**Edit**

So, if I understand well your data structure, try [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def merge_data(keys, data)
  keys.each_with_object([]) { |hash, obj| data.first.map { |k,v| if hash.values.first == k then obj << hash.merge(v) end } }
end

keys = [
         {:first_name => "blake"},
         {:first_name => "ashley"}
       ]

data = [{
        "blake" => {
            :awesomeness => 10,
            :height => "74",
            :last_name => "johnson"},
        "ashley" => {
            :awesomeness => 9,
            :height => 60,
            :last_name => "dubs"}
        }]

merge_data(keys, data)

#=> [{:first_name=>"blake", :awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74", :last_name=>"johnson"}, {:first_name=>"ashley", :awesomeness=>9, :height=>60, :last_name=>"dubs"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was because I had to merge that other _pointless_ hash in

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [{ :first_name=> "ashley" }, { :first_name=>"blake" }]    
data = [{ "blake"  => { :awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74", :last_name=>"johnson" },
          "margo"  => { :awesomeness=>30, :height=>"63", :last_name=>"magpie"  },
          "ashley" => { :awesomeness=>9,  :height=>"60", :last_name=>"dubs"    } }]
```

I suggest doing this in two steps. The first is to construct a more suitable data structure for the contents of `data`, namely, a hash:

```
data_adj = data.reduce(&:merge)
   #=> {"blake" =>{:awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74", :last_name=>"johnson"},
   #    "margo" =>{:awesomeness=>30, :height=>"63", :last_name=>"magpie"},
   #    "ashley"=>{:awesomeness=>9,  :height=>"60", :last_name=>"dubs"}}
```

The second is to merge the hashes in `keys` with the appropriate values of `data_adj`:

```
keys.map { |h| h.merge(data_adj[h[:first_name]]) }
  #=> [{:first_name=>"ashley", :awesomeness=>9,  :height=>"60", :last_name=>"dubs"},
  #    {:first_name=>"blake",  :awesomeness=>10, :height=>"74", :last_name=>"johnson"}]
```

This approach would be particularly efficient if the merging operation were to be performed repeatedly, for different values of `keys`, as `data_adj` need only be computed once. Dividing the problem into two also speeds testing.